# How to periodically change background image

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have 2 forms, frmMain and frmPictures. In frmMain I have a timer whose interval is 5000 (5 seconds). frmPictures has 16 pictureboxes with images already loaded in them. In each timer tick I need to change the frmMain background image.. on startup the background image is the same as picturebox1.
On each timer tick, the program should randomly select a PictureBox in frmPictures and change the background image of frmMain to the image of the selected PictureBox.
How do I do this in VB.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should gather all `PictureBoxes` in an array or similar structure. That can happen e.g. in the `Form_Load` event:

```
Dim pictures(15) As PictureBox
pictures(0) = frmPictures.PictureBox1
'...
```

Btw, why do you have PictureBoxes for each picture? It would be sufficient to load the images at application startup:

```
Dim pictures(15) As Image
pictures(0) = Image.FromFile("...")
'...
```

Then in the timer event, create a random number and pick an image:

```
'Call Randomize() on application startup
Dim rnd = CInt(16 * Rnd())
BackgroundImage = pictures(rnd).Image 'For the picture box method or
BackgroundImage = pictures(rnd)       'For the direct method
```